# Bootstrapping example ISL - pages 194-195

Tags: r, bootstrap, simulation, computational-statistics, resampling

I'm currently learning about bootstrapping using the book Introduction to Statistical Learning, and am struggling to understand what the point of using the `boot` function in R is - in the example in the book.

In the book, they use bootstrapping to try and estimate the alpha value - given by what is in the `return` function, below:

```
> alpha.fn=function (data ,index){
+ X=data$X[index]
+ Y=data$Y[index]
+ return ((var(Y)-cov(X,Y))/(var(X)+var(Y) -2*cov(X,Y)))
+ }
```

The data-set they use for the example, Portfolio, has 100 entries, and they do this to estimate the value:

```
> alpha.fn(Portfolio ,1:100)
[1] 0.576
```

They later go on to sample `R` times, with replacement, in order to estimate this same value:

```
> set.seed(1)
> alpha.fn(Portfolio ,sample (100,100, replace=T))
[1] 0.596
```

After which, they run the `boot` function in R, in order to run a bootstrap over 1000 iterations, as such:

```
library(boot)
> boot(Portfolio ,alpha.fn,R=1000)
ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
Call:
boot(data = Portfolio , statistic = alpha.fn, R = 1000)
Bootstrap Statistics :
    original bias std. error
t1* 0.5758 -7.315e-05 0.0886
```

Which is the exact same value as the original estimate, via our dataset of 100 observations above.

So my questions are: What was the point if the estimated value is identical, to that simulated 'normally' with the original dataset and without replacement? Is it simply to obtain a standard error + bias in order to generate other statistics - Confidence Intervals etc.? How do you run the same command with replacement, as in the second example, using the `boot` function?

Thank you!

Comment: The package is called `boot` as well, I edited the code above to include loading the library.

Comment: Notice that you also got estimates of bias and standard error. That's why. (The book will have explained this already.)

Comment: My understanding was that the strength of bootstrap comes from being able to sample with replacement.. Is the estimate derived without replacement, while the standard error is derived with replacement?

Comment: `boot` is just a convenience function. You can of course always write the resampling loop yourself and also calculate the resulting statistics (bias, standard error, confidence intervals) yourself. You should actually do so for didactic purposes. Using package `boot` just makes all of this easier (and you need to spend less time on programming and there is less room for programming mistakes).

Comment: The estimate shown is calculated without bootstrapping. Bootstrapping is used to estimate the uncertainty of an estimate.

Comment: OK I see, thank you for that clarification.